# C++ Vector error, Showing the variable is ambiguous - i have tried everything still no hope

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, vector

I am using eclipse luna with C++ ADT
I already set the compiler to compile c++11 and microprocessor and paths of project settings to c++11

**I am trying to create a simple vector and i am getting a bug showing :**

```
a2' is ambiguous '
Candidates are:
 vector(unsigned int, const std::allocator<double> &)
 vector(unsigned int, const double &, const std::allocator<double> &)
'
```

**The code i wrote is :**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<array>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    double a1[4] = {1.2,2.4,3.6,4.8};
    vector<double> a2(3);

    array<double,5> a3;

}
```

array is working fine but vector is coming up with error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `double a1[] = {1.2, 2.4, 3.6, 4.8}`?

Comment: no it is 
vector<double> a1(4) = {1.5,1.6,1.8,1.9};

Comment: i am getting error on the vector variable a2

Comment: That's not what you have written in your question? At the moment you are trying to assign an initializer list to a variable of type `double`

Comment: Do you expect a2 to be a vector of size 3 containing 0.0, 0.0, 0.0?

Comment: Completely different error given [here](http://ideone.com/Ewvd3v).

Comment: yes i am trying to create a vector of type double by list initializing the values

Comment: But you're not list-initializing the vector? Please match your code with what you're telling us you're trying to do.

Comment: Remove the lines which do not give the compilation error, please. Let the code you post be atomic

Comment: Moreover cannot be reproduced if the above mentioned error is fixed: http://ideone.com/zsDjjS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can glean from your question, you wish to create a vector with 3 `double` elements which have been default-intialized?

It is a good idea when working with the standard library to get used to documentation like [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). If we look at the documentation for [`std::vector::vector` on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), we can see that the constructor we want has the following signature:

```
explicit vector( size_type count );
```

So we can do the following to achieve your aim ([Ideone here](http://ideone.com/pW5aao)):

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> ourVec( 3U ); // Will result in 3 default-intialized doubles
}
```

More commonly, we wish to initialize the elements with some value (`0.0` could probably be a good choice here), looking at the cppreference, we can see the following prototype:

```
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

We can show this works using the following code (the [Ideone is here](http://ideone.com/NiT6un)):

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> ourVec( 3U, 0.0 ); // Will result in {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
}
```

If you wish to explicitly specify elements when you intialize the vector, you can use this using the `std::initializer_list` constructor:

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

We can use this as follows ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/plNh6y)):

```
#include <vector>
int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> ourVec = {1.2, -1.9, 0.1, 0.0} 
}
```

Comment: Your code is working and thanks for making it very clear

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring `double a1 = {1.2,2.4,3.6,4.8};`,

In `vector<double> a2(3);` the compiler is trying to figure out which constructor you want to invoke and the two your implementation has that are candidates are:

> ```
> vector(unsigned int, const std::allocator<double> &)
> vector(unsigned int, const double &, const std::allocator<double> &)
> ```

Do you just want to reserve space?

```
vector<double> a2{};
a2.reserve(3);
```

Or initialize with 3 elements?

```
vector<double> a2{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
```

Comment: i want to create a vector array of type double with 4 elements so that i can assign values later in the program like: 
a2[0] = 1.4;
a2[1] = 1.5;
a2[2] = 1.6;

Comment: @krishnamraju `double a1[] = {1.2, 2.4, 3.6, 4.8};` Just adding the brackets to your code will do it.